# avoid all mouse over, focus highlight CSS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement where i shall avoid only mouse over highlight onto the rows of table.

Whether, the highlight shall be there when i am using `tab` key to navigate through the rows.

```
<table>
   <tr><td>Row1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Row1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Row1</td></tr>
</table>
```

For highlight, i have written below rule

```
table tr:hover{
  background: yellow
}
```

JS fiddle link is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f06hb2yn/)

No highlight shall happen on mouseover but shall happen on using TAB..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `:focus` in conjunction with setting `tabindex` attributes on your rows should do the trick.  I've included a Fiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/3zsc7nok/

**EDIT**

You can use a bit of jQuery to prevent the default browser action on `mousedown` for the rows in order to prevent the highlighting by mouse action:

```
$('tr').on("mousedown", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Updated Fiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/s00xgt2s/

Comment: tabindex is not preferrable.. :) and i click on row then i am able to see highlight

Comment: Sure, because clicking on an element with the mouse will give it focus.  Your requirement mentions that the rows should not highlight on `mouseover`, which would be governed by a `:hover` style rule.  Do you mean to say that your requirements do not allow *any* mouse-driven interactions to display the highlight style?

Comment: yuo.. no mousedriven highlights shall be there,,,, only tab highlights

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure HTML/CSS example. You can simply use the `pointer-events: none` property, and then style the row on `:focus` rather than `:hover`.

Here's a fiddle with two examples:

- 1st will allow you to either click or tab through the options.
- 2nd will only allow you to tab through them.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2jxkdxu/1/)

Comment: Nice work on the `pointer-events`!  :) A word of caution, though: that CSS property isn't supported in IE10 or earlier.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: Good but not preferrbale Pointer events

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using plain Css why dont you try using jquery?
Something like this

```
$("tr").keydown(function (e) {    
  if (e.which == 9) {     
    $(this).css(" background","yellow");
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Please tell me if it works.

Comment: JQuery i have not used as i wa snot pretty sure if this is crossbrowser thing to handle or not